# Bind property to value of parent property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My Google-Fu is low today, cause I just can't find the answer to this really trivial problem:

I am creating my own custom control in XAML which inherits from `UserControl`. Inside it I have a `Grid` and some `TextBlock`s.

Now, I want whoever that uses my control to be able to set the property `Background` on my control. Then I want to use that `Background` value to set the `Background` property on my `Grid`.

Here's my XAML with my latest attempt:

```
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<Page> <!-- snipped all namespace-stuff -->
  <local:Foo Background="Red" Foreground="White"/>
</Page>
```

And the custom control:

```
<!-- Foo.xaml -->
<UserControl Name="UC"> <!-- snipped all namespace-stuff -->
  <Grid Background="{Binding Path=Background, ElementName=UC}">
    <TextBlock Text="My custom control"/>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Could you also post a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this (background for grid is left as an exercise for the reader...):

```
<UserControl Name="UC">

  <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding ElementName=UC, Path=Foreground}"/>  

</UserControl>
```

full example:

```
<Window x:Class="UnrelatedTests.Case8.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:case8="clr-namespace:UnrelatedTests.Case8"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <case8:UserControl1  Background="Blue" Foreground="Red"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>



<UserControl x:Class="UnrelatedTests.Case8.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"

             Name="UC1"
             >
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Background="White"  Foreground="{Binding ElementName=UC1, Path=Foreground}">Text</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[image: design and runtime view]

Comment: It does work in the designer of the `UserControl` but I get no colors in either the designer of the control using the `UserControl` or at runtime.

Comment: Added the XAML. The `Foreground` seems to be inherited so that one works without the need of any bindings. So I removed that part from my question. Still having issues with `Background` on the `Grid`, though.

Comment: Works for me. Even if I drop the binding. Background and Foreground are inherited anyway. What exactly is your problem? Background is not as specified on the user control?

Comment: I made a new project with your code and it works, so the issue is on my side. But I'll figure it out. Your code works at least, so I accepted your answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use RelativeSource on the binding for the TextBlock to use the property from the parent grid.

e.g.

```
{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}
```

Comment: `The property 'AncestorType' was not found in type 'RelativeSource'`